# Подчистить объект от пустых элементов

Tags: объекты, javascript

Как можно удалить из объекта пустые элементы.
Есть очень большой объект и проверять его таким способом не хотелось бы

```
if( ! obj.fields.field) delete obj.fields.field;
```

Вот часть объекта

```
var arr = { data: 
   { field: { field2: '' },
     field3: '',
     field4: '',
     field5: '1',
     field6: '',
     field7: { field8: true },
  },
  field9: { field10: '', field11: 'name' }
}
```

На выходе хотелось бы получить

```
var arr = { data: 
  {
     field5: '1',
     field7: { field8: true },
  },
  field9: { field11: 'name' }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двигайтесь в этом направлении:

```
var cleanObject = (function () {
    // Проверка значения
    function isEmpty(value) {
        return value === '';
    }

    // Export
    return function (obj) {
        var all = 0, deleted = 0;

        for (var key in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                all++; // всего свойств

                var value = obj[key];

                if (
                       isEmpty(value)
                    || (value instanceof Object && cleanObject(value))
                ) {
                    delete obj[key];
                    deleted++; // удаленных
                }
            }
        }

        return !(all - deleted); // true — объект пуст
    };
})();
```

P.S. Нужно ещё проверить работу с вложенными массивами и другими типами.

Comment: не пойму, а как сохранить структуру объекта.
К примеру если выше приведенный объект перебрать таким методом то на выходе получу объект такого плана:

    { field11: 'name' }

а нужно чтобы структура соответствовала предоставленной

    { field9: {field11: 'name' }}

Comment: @webphp ну так рекурсией, если вложенный элемент объект - то просто прогоняйте его через эту же функцию, если функция возвращает true, до удаляйте элемент.

Comment: Не очень понял, сейчас если передать функции ваш объект, на выходе получим, как в примере: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2vxhaeqbpgc5rbe/Screenshot%202014-08-07%2018.46.59.png

Comment: RubaXa, просто я дурачок, делал проверку так

    console.log(cleanObject(arr));

У меня естественно вызывалось false.

Вроде все работает, спс большое.

Comment: Бывает, надо было сделать, что функция возвращала объект, но тогда надо, чтобы он был новый, а не модифицировать старый и это уже сложней :]

Comment: это получается что нужно так же проверить есть ли значение, если оно есть то добавить в новый объект? Мне просто сейчас нужно еще проверить значение строка или число, если число то и в объекте сделать его числом. 
Попробую функцию слепить, может что и получится =)